# Hotkey to switch between Preview and Write

Tags: github

Is this possible to quickly switch between the Preview and the Write modes in the Wiki editor of the GitHub website? I mean without using the mouse at all.

[image: GitHub Markdown preview pane]

Answer (score 2):

`cmd + shift + p` - Toggles between the **Write** and **Preview** tabs.

See the [Issues and Pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.21/github/getting-started-with-github/keyboard-shortcuts#issues-and-pull-requests) shortcuts for more info.

Comment: This works. Firefox users can use `ctrl + shift + p` (the shortcut with cmd collides with the shortcut to open a new private window)

Answer (score 1):

Not with GitHub directly, as its [shortcut page](https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/) does not mention edit or preview.

You would need some userscript like [GitHub Markdown Preview](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/65788) in order to enhance GitHub GUI.